# Custom dialog made from DialogFragment does not display the dialog title

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I have created a custom error dialog fragment,
The displayed dialog is able to display the error message and the button.
However, the title does not display on the dialog.

```
class ErrorDialog(private val message: String): BaseMvcDialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(message: String): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog(message)
    }

    private lateinit var errorController : ErrorController
    private lateinit var  dialogEventBus: DialogEventBus

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        errorController = compositionRoot.errorController
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        dialogEventBus = compositionRoot.dialogEventBus
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val viewMvc = compositionRoot.viewMvcFactory.errorViewMvcImpl(null)
        val dialog = Dialog(requireContext())
        dialog.setContentView(viewMvc.getRootView())
        dialog.setTitle("Oops something went wrong....")
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        errorController.bindView(viewMvc, message, dialogEventBus)
        return dialog
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        errorController.onStart()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        errorController.onStop()
    }
}
```

The themes class

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.WeatherApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: Displayed dialog]

I have tried making changes to the themes, by adding a custom dialog theme
and this did not seem to work

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `AlertDialog` instead of `Dialog`, or `onCreateView()` instead of `onCreateDialog()`.

Comment: I have tried using the oncreateview and that does not make a difference

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when you are working with a device that has an API greater than 23
this line default to true.

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

To resolve this issue, I had to make some changes to my theme as seen below

```
<style name="Theme.WeatherApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

You also need to make sure that you are inheriting from the same parent theme